# Redirect back to original state after login - with params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i recently upgraded from UI-Router v0.4.2 to v1.0.0 RC1.

I used to work with $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(.. to capture the necesary data to be able to redirect back to the original page request after the user logged in.

Since upgrading to v1.0.0 i'm struggling to find something that works. Getting the from state name is a bit of a hassle on its own, but actually getting the url parameters is something else.

I have read through the docs and API info about the injectables and Transitions and States. The Sample App seems to address only a basic redirect (based on state name only).

Obviously, i'm missing something. ***Mind you, the params can vary.***

```
$transitions.onBefore({
    to: function (state) {
        return globals.anonymousStates.indexOf(state.name) == -1;
    }
}, function (transition) {
    return LoginService.isAuthenticatedV2(transition, "account.login");
});
```

*globals.anonymousStates* contains a list of states (string) that do not require authentication (currently two pages: account.login, account.forgotpassword).

The *LoginService.isAuthenticatedV2* contains the following code:

```
loginService.isAuthenticatedV2 = function (trans, redirectTo) {

        return $http.get('/Account/IsAuthenticated').then(function (result) {

            if (result.data.authenticated === true) {
                return trans;
            } else {
                return trans.router.stateService.target(redirectTo);
            }
        }, function (error) {
            return trans.router.stateService.target(redirectTo);
        })
    }
```

**In short:** When the user directly targets a url that requires authentication, he gets redirected to the *account.login* state. After that login, i want to redirect him to the original request, including all of the url parameters (an id, type, search, ..)

Example url: www.dummy.com/customer?id=007&type=bond&search=james

**Can anyone provide me with some help on how to tackle this issue?**

**EDIT**
I've tried getting the last "valid" state like this, getting the name like this works fine (as expected) but grabbing the params isn't working.

```
// copy the last valid redirectable state to the global service.
$transitions.onBefore({
    to: function (state) {
        if (globals.anonymousStates.indexOf(state.name) == -1) {
            globals.lastValidState = angular.copy(state);
        }
        return false;
    }
}, angular.noop);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it's just "transition.params()" to get all the params of the current transition.